# javascript add or merge to object

Tags: javascript, object

I am stuck. I am looking for a solution to add or create data in objects. 
For example, I start with an empty object.

```
var Foo = {};
```

How can I assign values to an object key without checking if the key "clicked" already excists?

```
{
    'clicked' : [
        {'foo' : 'bar'},
        {'blah', 'blaat'}
    ]
}
```

Usually you would do:

```
Foo.clicked = [];
Foo.clicked.push({'foo' : 'bar'});
Foo.clicked.push({'blah', 'blaat'});
```

Is there a more elegant way to assign data to Foo without checking if the key "clicked" is already there? Some sort of merge if it excists?

I have tried something like:

```
Object.assign({'click' : [{'foo':'bar'}]}, {'click' : [{'blah':'blaat'}]})
```

but the last one is overwriting the first one.

Comment: `let b = Object.assign({},{'click' : [{'foo':'bar'},{'blah':'blaat'}]})` ? , but you can't do it without checking you need to check for existence of key before adding anything

Comment: There is no magical way to check if the value already exists. You need to make the check and decide what you want to do. You could however, use a merging library such as [deepmerge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge) but that will overwrite values.

Comment: Depends what expected behaviors and results are ....which currently isn't very clear

Comment: You could use an object to store the keys, instead of an array. Then simply assigning would overwrite previous values.

Comment: why not simply initialize your Foo  as  `var Foo = { clicked : [] }` instead of an empty object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a check with a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) and assign an array, if the first operand (the property) is falsy.

```
Foo.clicked = Foo.clicked || [];
Foo.clicked.push({ foo: 'bar' });
Foo.clicked.push({ blah: 'blaat' });
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a more elegant way to assign data to Foo without checking if
>   the key "clicked" is already there?

You can straightforwardly use:

```
if (Foo.hasOwnProperty('clicked') !== true) {

  [... CODE HERE...]

}
```

to return a boolean, indicating that the property `'clicked'` does not already exist.

Comment: Sure. Either / or. (I'm writing longhand for the sake of clarity).